# file-loader does not work with dynamic url in angular

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-file-loader, dynamic-url

Does `file-loader` ignore dynamic url?

```html
// app.component.html
<img src="../assets/flower.jpeg" alt="Flower" width="100px">
<img src="{{assets}}flower.jpeg" alt="Flower" width="100px">
```

```js
// app.component.ts
export class AppComponent {
  assets = '../assets/';
}
```

As you can see I have 2 images in html. The first image is displayed as expected, but the second one does not work.

The first image is generated and image url in html is also changed, whereas second image url is not hashed.

```html
//eg:
<img src="./assets/b16683a9edb6ebf57d144f8b86cb163e.jpeg" alt="Flower" width="100px">
<img src="../assets/flower.jpeg" alt="Flower" width="100px">
```

Here is the [git repo](https://github.com/sameerthekhans/file-loader-issue.git) to reproduce issue, Run `npm i && npm start`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular case - yes, your path is simply ignored as an incorrect one. However, if your change it to `./{{assets}}flower.jpeg` (just for example) you'll get an error

> ERROR in Cannot find module './{{assets}}flower.jpeg'

Why is that happen? `{{assets}}` is an Angular binding and the exact value will be known only during the application run not during the building process. So the only way this path can be handled during the building process is just like it is and consequently, `file-loaded` cannot find any file on this incorrect path and gives you an error.

I hope I've explained the issue pretty clear. However, feel free to ask more questions in the comments if some details are not clear for you.

Comment: So I think there is no use of `file-loader` in my case, I should use `copy-webpack-plugin` to simply copy my assets to output directory and reference that path. Also there is no chance of hashing assets path/name ?

Comment: There are some options to add hashes to file name, however, (as far as I know) there is no way, in this case, to pass this hash into your code so the application would know the new filename

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind like this

```html
<img src='{{ "assets/images/" + wonder.id + ".jpg" }}' />
```

`[]` is not compatible with `{{ }}`.

Answer (score 0):

I made this example and it works
The fisrt is an html with the code
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO53f.png)
The second is the
[.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATLWE.png)
I wrote a variable in the ts called path where I put the url of my image then I use binding in the property src in the html and I send the variable path.
So when I click the button called 'change' the image change dynamically

Comment: You tried with the CDN image, try with local image.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,
`<img [src]="assets+'flower.jpeg'" alt="Flower" width="100px">`
Change path to asset as follows
`assets = 'assets/';`

Comment: Have you change the path to asset folder too?

Comment: Yes! I changed path, Actually I am hashing image name with file loader. This works If I give path in `src` itself, But when I use same path as dynamic, It didn't work. I think `file-loader` just ignores it, Because `file-loader` neither generated image in `assets` with hash nor changed path in image `src`